# Adobe embedded PDF save to Server giving corrupt file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am using Adobe Document Services PDF Embed API to display PDF files in my website and Iam allowing users to add sticky notes in the pdf and then save it

My problem is that i need to save the file back to the Server. But I cant find the PDF Buffer. I need to send the pdf buffer or the updated pdf to my Asp.net Conbtroller

```
  adobeDCView.previewFile({
            /* Pass information on how to access the file */
            content: {
                /* Location of file where it is hosted */
                location: {
                    url: myurl,
                },
            },
            /* Pass meta data of file */
            metaData: {
                /* file name */
                fileName: "-VER - 0.pdf"
            }
        }, viewerConfig);
    
        /* Define Save API Handler */
        var saveApiHandler = function (metaData, content, options) {
            console.log(metaData, content, options);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                /* Dummy implementation of Save API, replace with your business logic */
/
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('metaData', metaData);
                formData.append('content', content); // is this the pdf buffer ??? 
                formData.append('options', options);
                setTimeout(function () {
 //Want to do ajax call to controller here

                        var response = {
                            code: AdobeDC.View.Enum.ApiResponseCode.SUCCESS,
                            data: {
                                metaData: Object.assign(metaData, { updatedAt: new Date().getTime() })
                            },
                        };
                        resolve(response);
                    }, 2000);
               
                
               
            });
        };
```

And in my controller I have

```
[HttpPost ]
    public ActionResult GetData(object Metadata, Object content,object option)
    {
      
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())            {
            bf.Serialize(ms, content);           
           System.IO. File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\1.pdf", ms.ToArray());
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I have a working example at this Codepen. In my example, the PDF gets saved locally but you can use the same technique to submit it to a server.
https://codepen.io/practicalPDF/pen/NWNywVo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @joelgeraci suggested  Need to convert the content to base64 and add it to form data and send to Controller action( credits to the codepen provided by @joelgeraci

```
   var base64PDF = arrayBufferToBase64(content);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('content', base64PDF);
```

Function to convert arraybuffer

```
function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
        var binary = "";
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        return window.btoa(binary);
    }
```

And in the controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetData(object Metadata, Object content, object option, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> productImg, String DocumentID, string filename)
        {           
            byte[] sPDFDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(((string[])content)[0]);
            string filepath = "C:\1.pdf";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, sPDFDecoded);
            return View();
        }
```